# Add layers in blender 2.93

Tags: animation, windows, 2d, layers

I am new to blender I downloaded it just now. I am trying to add a new layer in 2D Animation but I don't know how to.

[image: Screen shot of Blender]

I am using Windows 10.

Any help will be accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the button that looks like a green squiggly line farther down that column - Those are your stroke properties, where you can add layers (with the <kbd>+</kbd> button), and adjust other stroke-related settings.

[image: Layers]

Comment: Thanks it works. Can I select the character to copy and paste it in every frame? I am creating a simple stick-man.

Comment: Yes. There are even more efficient ways to do things like that, as well as many other things, but much more than I can describe here. If you want a good tutorial series to get started, I personally like this one by _Default Cube_ - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7qZWW0k41WA